# Перенос сайта на Битрикс на другой хостинг в ручную

Tags: битрикс, домен, scp

Самое первое - делается это не через бэкап, и через бэкап этого не сделать, никак. Почему и критика ручного переноса не являются темой этого вопроса.

Второе - делаю scp, (вообще есть несколько сайтов, но не на всех есть дамп бд), начинаю с того сайта где дампа бд нет.
Открываю новый домен:

```
Bitrix Environment
This product is under the License Agreements of various software components used in BitrixEnv. The most components come with the GNU General Public License. However, the following exceptions exist
```

Битрикс окружение ставить не собираюсь, потому что нет доступа к руту

Как заставить сайт работать или другие способы переноса?

Comment: Измените постановку вопроса. Не ясно, что вы делаете. Перенос вручную любой CMS состоит из 4 действий 1) перенос файлов 2) перенос БД 3) исправление конфигурации CMS и веб-сервера 4) опционально: добавление заданий в cron, установка дополнительного ПО. Что делали, на чем застряли?